# Excel check and replace the digit after decimal

Tags: excel-formula

I have a figure in Excel. For example `Cell A1: 241.86`.

How do I check and change the last digit. For example, if it is greater or equal to 6 then replace it to 5, else remain the same. `Eg: 241.86 to 241.85.`

I have tried the following:

```
=IF(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+2,5)>=6,REPLACE(A3,3,2,A1-0.01),A1)
```

The above formula doesn't work, whenever its 241.86 or 241.84 the result will be 241.85 and 241.83. It simply minus 1 from the last digit. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What about 241.81, 241.82, 241.83 and 241.84? Should they be rounded down to 241.80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to manipulate a number. Replace() is a text function and will not do what you describe.

If you only want to round down numbers where the second decimal is greater than 5, then try

```
=IF(ROUND(MOD(A1,0.1),2)>=0.06,FLOOR(A1,0.05),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you teylyn my friend.